# Celery: Numerous small tasks or one long running task?

Tags: django, celery

I have a Django app and using Celery to process long running tasks.

Let's say I need to generate a file (takes 5 seconds), attach it to an email and send it to 1000 users, which of these methods are the preferred way?

**Method 1**: For loop outside task - generates numerates background tasks, each running a couple of seconds

```
@share_task
def my_task(usr):
    #gen file + send email...

def send_to_all_users(users):  # called to start task
    for usr in users:
        my_task.delay(usr)
```

**Method 2**: For loop inside task - generates 1 background tasks that could be running for hours

```
@share_task
def my_task(users):
    for usr in users:
        #gen file + send email...

def send_to_all_users(users):  # called to start task
    my_task.delay(users)
```

With method 1, I can scale up the number of workers to complete the entire task quicker, but creating all those tasks might take a while and I'm not sure if my task queue can fill up and then jobs get discarded?

Method 2 seems simpler, but it might run a very long time and I can't scale up the number of workers.

Not sure if it matters, but my app is running on Heroku and I'm using Redis as the message broker. I'm currently using a single background worker.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12307173, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7493306

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Celery docs on [Task Granularity](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#granularity):

> The task granularity is the amount of computation needed by each
>   subtask. **In general it is better to split the problem up into many
>   small tasks rather than have a few long running tasks**.
>
> With smaller tasks you can process more tasks in parallel and the
>   tasks won’t run long enough to block the worker from processing other
>   waiting tasks.
>
> However, executing a task does have overhead. A message needs to be
>   sent, data may not be local, etc. So if the tasks are too fine-grained
>   the overhead added probably removes any benefit.

So the first method should be preferred *in general*, but you have to benchmark your particular case to assess the overhead.

Comment: Great thanks. Maybe its best then to send it in batches to the background worker, such as 100 entries per background job

Comment: I'd start with a task per user (1st method) and move to batching only if there's a real need for that. Perhaps I'd even split `my_task` into `gen_file` and `send_email` subtasks for more control, like separate queues and workers: one with multiprocessing pool for file generation and another one with [async pool](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#concurrency-eventlet) for email sending.